sending command to VideoJet 2351 printer using TCP/IP
its my first question on this forum, so im sorry if i made any mistakes in its review.
Im trying to set a connection and send a command to printer, using this code:
import socket

# Connection options
HOST = 'IP_Adress'  
PORT = 3001  


def connect_to_printer():
    try:
        # socket creation
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            # connecting to the printer
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))
            print("Connection established.")

            # trying to send a command
            command = b'GST\r>'  # There was many different 
            s.sendall(command)


            # receaving of an answer
            response = s.recv(4096)  
            print("Printer answer:", response.decode())

    except socket.error as e:
        print(f"Connection error: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_printer()

but im recieving an empty answer on any form of ASCII command i've tried.
socket opens successfully.
I've tried to write different forms of command, but nothing could help.
I think I have made a mistake in ASCII command coding, but I couldn't find clear rules for writing them when it comes to the printer of this model.
could you please tell me, how should i write ASCII command correctly, or is it just a connection problem?
